# FlotCharts: Many different series at the same chart impact Legend display very badly

Tags: javascript, html, charts, show, flot

When there is 10+ series in a Scatter plot for examples - Legend look really bad.. It just extends to bottom of the screen - crossing chart area etc.

What it would be nice is to have a drop-down list that allows multiple selections :
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple

And color / legend next to each selection outside of the chart (not inside the chart).
That way it would be elegant solution for many series where user can scroll down and select multiple series at once that he/she wants to see (not clicking only 1 at the time)..

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of series, I would recommend to build the legend yourself. Just loop over your complete dataset and generate the HTML yourself, I have used tables with checkboxes for this before where there are also checkboxes for every column and row.

You could (de-)activate a series in the chart with each click on a checkbox or only update the chart after clicking a dedicated button. To update the chart loop over the checkboxes and copy the corresponding data series from the cmoplete dataset to a second dataset for the current chart. This should work similar with a multiple select.

The basic functionality is shown in [this example](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/series-toggle/index.html). Just remove the default legend and add the colors to the outside legend with the checkboxes.

In general it is also possible to have multiple columns in the default legend or to move the default legend outside the chart to a given container. See the [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-legend).

Comment: Do you maybe have example in JSFiddle or somewhere about the example that you did with table / clicking.. I have troubles creating specific Html based on a legend..